# Why does my Google Sheets QUERY function return product(n())?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a query function that provides 2 columns of data of a Name and a Value. When I try to multiply the 2nd Select column identifier by an amount in the QUERY string, it returns a blank on the cell itself, and product(2()) on the column next to it, with my data below. If I don't use arithmetic operators, the query returns correctly without any strange labels.

Working query:

```
=QUERY(IndustryBlueprintData!A2:H32015, 
 "select G, H where C = '" & $B34 & " Blueprint' AND D = 1", 0)
```

[image: Result]

Strange label query (* 2 being a test value):

```
=QUERY(IndustryBlueprintData!A2:H32015, 
 "select G, (H * 2) where C = '" & $B34 & " Blueprint' AND D = 1", 0)
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

it's because of `(H * 2)` (eg. you creating a product of column **H** * 2)

to fix it you will need to label it out with `label (H * 2)''` like:

```
=QUERY(IndustryBlueprintData!A2:H32015,
 "select G, (H * 2) 
  where C = '" & $B34 & " Blueprint' 
    AND D = 1 
  label (H * 2)''", 0)
```